# .htaccess How allow directory

Tags: .htaccess

**folders on server**

```
/test
/test1
/test2
```

**.htaccess**

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from **.***.***.**
<Directory /test>
    Options +Indexes
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

We are use .htaccess but adress http://test.com/test/ not work. Tell me please where errror ?

Comment: What version of Apache are you running? Where is your `.htaccess` file stored?

Comment: @MikeRockett .htacces stored in root directory site.

Comment: And as for my first question? Apache version (run `httpd -v` in your terminal to find out)? Also, what error are you getting? When you provide little information in your question, it isn't easy for people to help you.